# I have some problems with my java simple project

Tags: java

I was looking to create a project but i'm a new java programmer and i'm not ablo to create it.

```
public class Funzioni {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("E' una funzione algebrica o aritmetica?");


    }

}
```

If the answer is algebrica, so...
if the answer is aritmetica, so..

Can someone help me with the if costruct?
thnak you so much

Comment: is the value in the args array?

Comment: can you describe your problem  more precise?

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funzioni {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("E' una funzione algebrica o aritetica?");
        Scanner userlnputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        userlnputScanner.nextLine();
        boolean algebrica = true;
        if E' una funzione algebrica o aritetica?==algebrica

Comment: why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, frlaka.

You just need to read from keyboard a String.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funzioni {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("E' una funzione algebrica o aritmetica?");
        String value;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        value=s.nextLine();
        if (value.equals("algebrica")){
            // do something
        } else if (value.equals("aritmetica")){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Have a good day!

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funzioni {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("E' una funzione algebrica o aritetica?");
        Scanner userlnputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        userlnputScanner.nextLine();
        boolean algebrica = true;
        if E' una funzione algebrica o aritetica?==algebrica
                                                                                                                            Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Because you can't compare a String with a Boolean variable. Try to use my example and you'll see it works.

Comment: I have seen it. I don't understandt in which case i have to use string and when i have to use the boolean variable

Comment: When you run your program, in your console, first of all, will appear "E' una funzione algebrica o aritmetica?" and then, the console will allow you to write something. If you write algebraica, then, the variable 'value' has "algebraica" value. In the if/else clause, your program will compare 'value' value with "algebraica". If you have written "algebraica", this will return 'true', so you execute what is inside the if (you could add a System.out.println("Algebraica selection");)